# Remove First Page from a Series of PDFs

Tags: bash, pdf, pdftk

I have a series of PDFs ([Computer Gaming World issues](http://kotaku.com/207655/100-issues-of-computer-gaming-world-free)) and I want to remove the first page from the pdf file of each issue. There are 100 issues, so a GUI is just not gonna cut it. I used pdftk to remove the first page from one issue:

```
pdftk 1981_1112_issue1.pdf cat 1 output 1.pdf
```

My problem is that I do not want to have to modify and run this command for every pdf issue as that is not much better than the GUI method.

Using *.pdf as an input does not seem to work. What other ways can I use to run pdftk on every PDF?

Comment: Is there a pattern in the naming of issues?

Comment: Not exactly...you'll notice the year is the first term in the filename, and the years definitely vary. But I could easily mass rename...

Comment: Do all the files have "issue" in their name?

Comment: They do. It's all year_quarter_issue#.pdf. also, pdftk *_issue*.pdf cat 1 output *.pdf seems to provide the correct input, but then what do I call the output file?

Comment: Your example command does **not** remove the 1st page from the input PDF. It extracts the 1st page from the input into a single page output PDF (1.pdf) and leaves the input untouched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop on all issues. Output is named after issue by replacing "issue" by "output". The first line extract page 1, the second line extract the other pages:

```
for issue in *_issue*.pdf
do
    pdftk ${issue} cat 1 output page1_${issue/issue/output}
    pdftk ${issue} cat 2-end output otherpages_${issue/issue/output}
done
```

Comment: Oh I see how this works. I have done some programming but I didn't realize how variables worked in bash. What exactly are you doing with ${issue/issue/output}?

Comment: ${a/b/c} replaces the b substring by the c substring in the contents of the a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.pdf
do
 out=${file%.pdf}_page1.pdf
 pdftk "$file" cat 1 output "$out"
done
```

Comment: I like this answer for its straightforwardness. Is the shopt line necessary?